# PHP __call() Magic Method Parsing Arguments

Tags: php

I'm working on a project and I want to try and 'lazy-load' objects.

I've setup a simple class using the Magic Method __call($name, $arguments).

What I'm trying to do is pass the $arguments through, not as an array, but as a list of variables:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    // Include the required file, it should probably include some error
    // checking
    require_once(PLUGIN_PATH . '/helpers/' . $name . '.php');

    // Construct the class name
    $class = '\helpers\\' . $name;    

    $this->$name = call_user_func($class.'::factory', $arguments);

}
```

However, in the method actually being called by the above, $arguments is being passed through as an array and NOT the single variables, E.G.

```
public function __construct($one, $two = null)
{
    var_dump($one);
    var_dump($two);
}
static public function factory($one, $two = null)
{
    return new self($one, $two);
}
```

Returns:

```
array
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string '2' (length=1)

null
```

Does this make sense, does anyone know how to achieve what I'm trying to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->$name = call_user_func_array($class.'::factory', $arguments);
```

instead of:

```
$this->$name = call_user_func($class.'::factory', $arguments);
```